# To count a column based on another column's repeating(same) entry

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to create a report of calls last made based on weeks from last call and call-Group

Actual Data is like below with call id, date of call and call grouping

```
callid |  Date   |   Group
----------------------------
1      | 6-1-18  |    a1
2      | 6-1-18  |    a2
3      | 7-1-18  |    a3
4      | 8-1-18  |    a1
5      | 9-1-18  |    a2
6      | 9-1-18  |    a4
```

Expected data is to display the number of calls for each call group corresponding to the number of week from last call

```
week   |     |
from   |     |
last   |Group|Group
call   |  a1 |  a2
--------------------
1      | 2   |  2 ->number of calls
2      | -   |  - 
3      | 1   |  - 
4      | 2   |  - 
5      | -   |  3  
6      | -   |  -
```

Can anyone please tell me some solution for this

Answer (score 1):

Although you data provided was a very small set and not rich enough to cover all cases, here is an sql that will calculate the number of weeks difference between each call and last call within a group and count the number of calls for each group for the particular week difference.

```
with your_table as (
select 1 as "callid", to_date('6-1-18','dd-mm-rr') as "date", 'a1' as "group" from dual
union select 2, to_date('6-1-18','mm-dd-rr'), 'a2' from dual
union select 3, to_date('7-1-18','mm-dd-rr'), 'a3' from dual
union select 4, to_date('8-1-18','mm-dd-rr'), 'a1' from dual
union select 5, to_date('9-1-18','mm-dd-rr'), 'a2' from dual
union select 6, to_date('6-1-18','mm-dd-rr'), 'a4' from dual
),
 data1 as (
select t.*, max(t."date") over (partition by t."group") last_call_dt from your_table t
),
data2 as (select  t.*, round((last_call_dt-t."date")/7,0) as weeks_diff from data1 t)
select * from (
select t.weeks_diff, t."callid", t."group" from data2 t
)
PIVOT
(
  COUNT("callid")
  FOR "group" IN ('a1', 'a2', 'a3','a4')
)
order by weeks_diff
```

to try it out with your table just make the following change:

with your_table as (select * from my_table), ....

let me know how it goes :)

Comment: Your are welcome @CyrilJason. Please don't forget to mark the answer as correct :)